# why does elastic beanstalk not update?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pyramid

I'm new to the world of AWS, and I just wrote and deployed a small Pyramid application. I ran into some problems getting set up, but after I got it working, everything seemed to be fine. However, now, my deployments don't seem to be making a difference in the environment (I changed the index.pt file that my root url routed to, and it does not register on my-app.elasticbeanstalk.com).

Is there some sort of delay to the deployments that I am unaware of, or is there a problem with how I'm deploying (`eb deploy` using the awsebcli package) that's causing these updates to my application to not show?

Comment: I'm having the same concern. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you committing your changes before deploying?

`eb deploy` will deploy the HEAD commit.

You can do `eb deploy --staged` to deploy staged changes.

Comment: Yup, I always commit, push, then deploy.